# How do I store rank for each website in MySQL using this API

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is an api which gives you rank of any website..

http://apps.compete.com/sites/google.com/trended/rank/?apikey=ee39792b8044f3d3b8bf38f6e1ec91fd&latest=1

I do have more than 1000 website list in note pad. what I want is I need to store rank for each website using this API to MySQL database. I want to do this from my local machine..I have configured webserver and PHP MySQL on it. How do I do this??

Can anyone give me a PHP code for this??

sorry the key was wrong I updated it

Comment: I get an access-denied error when I use that URL.

Comment: The above link doesnt shows an access denied message. Do you know how and with which file to communicate?
As a general solution, you can have the local *.txt file being read by a PHP script, and put the result into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you some idea:

```
<?php

//connect to your database
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("somedb");

//read your text file into an array, one entry per line
$lines = file('filename.txt');

//loop through each website URL you read from the file
foreach ($lines as $website_url) {

    //make the request to the compete API
    $response = file_get_contents("http://apps.compete.com/sites/" . $website_url . "/trended/rank/?apikey=0sdf456sdf12sdf1");

    //the error I saw was in JSON, so decode the request
    $response = json_decode($request);

    //get the rank from the response, I don't know what a real response looks like
    $rank = $response['something']; 

    //insert the website URL and its rank into your table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO website_ranks (website_url, rank) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($website_Url) . "', " . $rank . ")");

}

?>
```

I don't have enough details from you to write working code, though.

Comment: I think I've already given you enough to finish it yourself; I'll leave writing the `$rank = $response['something']` line as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Fine thanks I will try that...thought will update you thats why